# R: Run a loop from 4 vectors to output 4 data tables

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Everyone,

I have 4 vectors V1, V2, V3, V4 i want to run through a loop in an SQL query. Each vector is a list of numbers in this format ('8001', '8002', '8003') for my SQL query.
If I do a `vlist <- list(c(V1, V2, V3,V4))` it give me a list

```
> vlist
[[1]]
[1] "'84035','84040','84037','84013','84036','84030','84026','84016','84020','84012','84019'"
[2] "'84010','84039','84029','84031','84022','84032','84044','84034','84041','84042','84043'"
```

query

```
 #my code for the SQL query
vQuery <- infuse("SELECT TOP (1000) [PKID]
                           ,[Equipment]
                           ,[Order]
                           ,[ActStartDate]
                           ,[ActFinDate]
                           ,[ActStartTime]
                           ,[ActFinTime]
                           FROM [sapData].[dbo].[SAP_IW_47]
                           where Equipment IN ({{Vectors}}) 
                           and OrdCat = 'ZWAR'
                           and AcTyAct like '%TUT'
                           and ActStartDate BETWEEN '{{start}}' AND '{{end}}'"
                           , Vectors= #???, start = startdate, end = enddate) 
      # make it a data table
      VectorQuery <- queryDataHub(vQuery)
      vTable <- data.table(VectorQuery)
```

I am wanting to input the V1, V2, ... in the vQuery infused where `Vectors= #??`. Now What I am trying to do is have a possible for loop to run the code above, and when `vTable` code runs I have an output of 4 data tables V1table, V2 table, ..... Would a for-loop be best for this. I can copy and paste the entire code 4 different times, but would like to condense it down.

Comment: What is `infuse`? Is each vector really of numbers, or (as it appears) is each "vector" just a single string? Have you tried a `for` loop or `sapply`?

Comment: `sapply(vlist, function(v) infuse("SELECT ... IN ({{v}}) ...", v=v, ...))`

Comment: Infuse is from the R package infuser. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/infuser/infuser.pdf

Comment: It's good practice to make questions fully reproducible, including non-base packages required to make the code work. In this case, I don't know that it's strictly relevant since all you're asking to do is create a string that is then sent to whatever mechanism you need. Regardless, some good refs for reproducible questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting up a defined method for your process that receives a vector element. Then use `lapply` which is an iteration function that returns a list object with equal length as its input.

Unlike `for` loop, `lapply` avoids the bookkeeping task of initializing an empty list and assigning elements to it in each iteration which by the way is perfectly fine to do as well.

```
proc_query <- function(v) {
      vQuery <- infuse("SELECT TOP (1000) [PKID]
                           ,[Equipment]
                           ,[Order]
                           ,[ActStartDate]
                           ,[ActFinDate]
                           ,[ActStartTime]
                           ,[ActFinTime]
                           FROM [sapData].[dbo].[SAP_IW_47]
                           where Equipment IN ({{Vectors}}) 
                           and OrdCat = 'ZWAR'
                           and AcTyAct like '%TUT'
                           and ActStartDate BETWEEN '{{start}}' AND '{{end}}'"
                           , Vectors= v, start = startdate, end = enddate) 
      # make it a data table
      VectorQuery <- queryDataHub(vQuery)

      return(data.table(VectorQuery))
}

# LIST OF DATA TABLES
vTables <- lapply(vlist, proc_query)
```

Alternatively with `for` loop:

```
# INITIALIZE EMPTY LIST WITH DEFINED LENGTH
vTables <- vector("list", length(vlist))

for (i in seq_along(vlist)) {
   # UPDATE ELEMENTS
   vTables[[i]] <- proc_query(vlist[[i]])          # STILL CALLING DEFINED FUNCTION
}
```